# How's the thing iterated over called?

Tags: language-agnostic, iterator, const-iterator

I wanted to express that an iterator is const (i.e you cannot increment or decrement it) but that the thing it yields is non-const:

```
iterator const it = foo.begin();
it++; // error
*it = ...; // not an error
```

If `iterator` is a pointer, I can say:

> **pointer** *// the iterator*
>
> **pointee** *// the thing it yields*

But if it is not a pointer, I'm not sure. I thought about using `container` for the "pointee" substitute, but a iterator is not tied to a container at all. For example an input iterator can be tied to a file or to STDIN. Does the following work and is used by others?

> **iterator** *// the iterator*
>
> **iteratoo** *// the thing it yields*

I'm glad for any guidance!

Comment: I can't imagine the thing you describe not being a pointer.  Can you give an example of that?

Comment: @Paul: you can't imagine an iterator that isn't a pointer? What about an instance of `ostream_iterator` in C++, how can that possibly be a pointer? Or an iterator over a `Vector` in Java conceivably could be index-based rather than some JNI pointer-using optimization. In fact very few iterator types can actually *be* pointers, although in some cases you wouldn't be surprised if they had a pointer data member and no other data.

Comment: I've always referred to it as the **iteratee**, but now that you mentioned it and I took some time to Google the term, it doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Steve: By my reading, what is being described is an iterator that does not iterate.  i.e. an object that somehow points to a specific member of a collection, and cannot be modified to point to any other member.   While I agree that this might be not actually be a pointer itself (in the sense of a memory address), but instead an object that contains a pointer data member, or some other means of indexing that particular member;  The behaviour of this thing seems very pointery.

Comment: @Paul: in C++, the fact that you can't increment a particular object doesn't means that you can't increment a copy of it -- iterators have value semantics, and the constness Johannes is talking about is a property of a variable, not a property of the value that variable holds. `iterator const it = foo.begin(); it++ /* error */; iterator it2 = it; it2++; /* fine, points to the next thing in sequence */`. I don't think that a `char *const` is any more or less pointery than a `char*`, and I don't think that an `iterator const` is any more or less pointery than a `iterator`.

Answer (score 3):

Is "the value" too obvious (or wrong)?  After all, what you want out of the iterator is the value.  If you are referring to the set of values that you are iterating over then I think "sequence" is not a bad choice.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this here since we discussed this in the chat.

Use the victor/victim setup.

Iterator / Iteratim

Or you could use Iteratee.

Answer (score 2):

The *-and* suffix is used in English for 'thing to be acted on', for example the OED gives as examples *multiplicand* for 'thing to be multiplied', and *operand* for 'thing to be operated on'.

So what about **iterand** for 'thing to be iterated over'?

Comment: FWIW, my expectation would be that "iterand" means the container/file/stream/whatever that's is being iterated over, rather than the particular member of it that's the current focus.

Comment: Although a Google search suggests that I'm wrong to expect that. Drat.

Comment: @Steve: True: I see the possible confusion, particularly given my wording above.

Answer (score 2):

I would say "the referand" if I was saying it a lot, or "the thing the iterator points at" if I was just saying it once, and was worried about any confusion that someone might think I was talking about a C++ reference.

I also say "the referand" of a pointer (not the "pointee"). If people don't realise that pointers and iterators are both kinds of reference, despite not being specifically C++ references, they can always be educated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any derivatives of **iterator** - be it **iteratim**, **iteree**, **iteratee** or **iterand** or whatever else are appropriate. Why? Because an iterator doesn't ***do***  anything to the thing it points to. The words suggested by other answers imply that an **iteratim** or **iteratee** etc. is being iterated. But it isn't. It is being pointed to. A pointer points to the pointee. An iterator *doesn't* iterate the iteratee.

So I think best is to use the word **pointee**.

Answer (score 0):

An element of a collection, being iterated or not, is an item.